# Regarding Michelson's interferometer

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, experimental-physics, interference, interferometry

In Michelson's Interferometer (1881 experiment), even though the arm length for both the perpendicular arms was taken as the same  (say $L$) and a compensatory plate was used to removed optical path differences, we still get a proper interference pattern despite both the rays reaching the observational lens in parallel. Why is that the case?

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking but the rays are usually close to parallel on their way to the detection screen. Interference has more to do with the path lengths.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are confused between interference and interaction? Two light beams do not interact, they pass through each other, but they interfere because of the superposition of the electric and magnetic fields that describe them, whatever the angle between them. It is the coherence and phases that are important to get a pattern, not the angle, [see here.](https://waloinaz.people.amherst.edu/P34/P34s03labs/P34LAB9-TwoSource.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is about the role of the compensation plate, so I will answer this part.

Interferometers have the best performance when the contrast is optimized, i.e., when the dark fringe is completely dark. This is obtained when the light intensity emerging from the two beams is exactly the same.

Even if the beamsplitter splits the light equally into the two arms, having two beams at the output with exactly the same intensity is a hard task to achieve, as one of the beams crosses the beamsplitter one time, whereas the other crosses it 3 times, resulting in a larger attenuation.

Inserting a compensation plate with the same attenuation properties of the beamsplitter on the beam that goes through the beamsplitter only one time solves this problem.

The situation is well depicted in the following picture.

[image]

Comment: ohh..thanks guys for the answer.but i was just confused about a very basic issue..i did not know that one of the beam suffers an extra phase change (due to an extar bounce at rare-dense interface) and that for a collimated beam absolute darknes or brightness is achieved (without any classic fringes or rings)  if the two proper mirrors M1 and M2 are perpendicular to each other,

Answer (score 0):

Despite the pictures in the textbooks, in a real Michelson interferometer the mirrors are not *exactly* aligned at 90 and 45 degrees.  Just very close.

The observer at the eyepiece perceives two (coherent) images of the source, one reflected by the back mirror and one reflected by the side mirror. Because of the small misalignments they are not exactly superimposed, but displaced sideways. So they produce fringes just as the standard two-slit configuration does.